# Get EJB object inside rar deployed inside jboss

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, jndi, naming

I have an activemq broker deployed within my jboss server. 
activemq is deployed as a rar file placed in jboss standalone/deployment repository. 
An other project is also deployed within my jboss as an ear file.
This last is exposing some ejb objects in my jboss. 
I tried to get an ejb from a jar file that I put into my activemq rar file. A class placed within the jar is called when I connect a client to the broker.

**This is how I tried to get ejb within jar file:**

```
  Context ctx; 
  Properties jndiProps = new Properties(); 
  jndiProps.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming"); 
  jndiProps.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true); 
  ctx = new InitialContext(jndiProps); 
  Ctx.lookup("ejb:Hemis/HemisCoreClient//"+ "HardwareDataManagement" + "!" + "com.ubiant.hemis.client.ejb.interf.I_HardwareDataManagement");
```

**Log from jboss when ejb is exposed:**

*11:50:17,538 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-4) JNDI bindings for session bean named HardwareDataManagement in deployment unit subdeployment "HemisCoreClient.jar" of deployment "Hemis.ear" are as follows:*

java:global/Hemis/HemisCoreClient/HardwareDataManagement!com.ubiant.hemis.client.ejb.interf.I_HardwareDataManagement 
  java:app/HemisCoreClient/HardwareDataManagement!com.ubiant.hemis.client.ejb.interf.I_HardwareDataManagement 
  java:module/HardwareDataManagement!com.ubiant.hemis.client.ejb.interf.I_HardwareDataManagement 
  java:jboss/exported/Hemis/HemisCoreClient/HardwareDataManagement!com.ubiant.hemis.client.ejb.interf.I_HardwareDataManagement 
  java:global/Hemis/HemisCoreClient/HardwareDataManagement 
  java:app/HemisCoreClient/HardwareDataManagement 
  java:module/HardwareDataManagement*

**The log error when I try to connect client to the broker:**

*17:26:15,555 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) javax.naming.NameNotFoundException; remaining name 'java:Hemis/HemisCoreClient//HardwareDataManagement!com.ubiant.hemis.client.ejb.interf.I_HardwareDataManagement' 
17:26:15,556 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.local.localContextRoot.lookup(localContextRoot.java:490) 
17:26:15,557 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.local.localContextRoot.lookup(localContextRoot.java:536) 
17:26:15,557 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411) 
17:26:15,558 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at authentification.TokenAuthentificationBroker.addConnection(TokenAuthentificationBroker.java:46) 
17:26:15,558 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at org.apache.activemq.broker.MutableBrokerFilter.addConnection(MutableBrokerFilter.java:97) 
17:26:15,558 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.processAddConnection(TransportConnection.java:733) 
17:26:15,559 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagedTransportConnection.processAddConnection(ManagedTransportConnection.java:79) 
17:26:15,559 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at org.apache.activemq.command.ConnectionInfo.visit(ConnectionInfo.java:139) 
17:26:15,560 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.service(TransportConnection.java:292) 
17:26:15,561 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection$1.onCommand(TransportConnection.java:149) 
17:26:15,562 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.doConsume(TransportSupport.java:83) 
17:26:15,562 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at org.apache.activemq.transport.ws.MQTTSocket.sendToActiveMQ(MQTTSocket.java:112) 
17:26:15,563 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at org.apache.activemq.transport.mqtt.MQTTProtocolConverter.sendToActiveMQ(MQTTProtocolConverter.java:133) 
17:26:15,564 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at org.apache.activemq.transport.mqtt.MQTTProtocolConverter.onMQTTConnect(MQTTProtocolConverter.java:235) 
17:26:15,564 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at org.apache.activemq.transport.mqtt.MQTTProtocolConverter.onMQTTCommand(MQTTProtocolConverter.java:157) 
17:26:15,566 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at org.apache.activemq.transport.ws.MQTTSocket.onMessage(MQTTSocket.java:59) 
17:26:15,566 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketConnectionRFC6455$WSFrameHandler.onFrame(WebSocketConnectionRFC6455.java:860) 
17:26:15,567 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketParserRFC6455.parseNext(WebSocketParserRFC6455.java:349) 
17:26:15,568 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketConnectionRFC6455.handle(WebSocketConnectionRFC6455.java:225) 
17:26:15,568 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628) 
17:26:15,569 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52) 
17:26:15,571 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608) 
17:26:15,571 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543) 
17:26:15,572 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)*

**When I try this code from a class inside the ear which is exposing EJB, it work and I can get EJB object. Do I think that the problem is that I try to get ejb from jar included in rar deployed in my jboss. 
Could someone help me with this?**

Answer (score 0):

It should not be necessary to perform a remote lookup like that.

The following *should* work:

```
 Context ctx = new InitialContext();
 ... = ctx.lookup("java:global/Hemis/HemisCoreClient/HardwareDataManagement!com.ubiant.hemis.client.ejb.interf.I_HardwareDataManagement");
```

Objects in the `java:global/...` namespace are accessible from within any module deployed on the server instance.

Comment: Should I add something into my ra.xml file ?

Comment: You seem to have a `jetty-jndi.jar` (see `org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.local.localContextRoot.lookup` in stacktrace) in your rar file as well - what is that doing there?

Comment: I have two jetty jar files into my activemq rar: jetty-websocket.jar and jetty-all-server.jar. Jetty is used by activemq. I think that it is an internal server for activemq. I posted a question in activemq forum to see if the problem comes from jetty but I get a response saying that it's related to jndi problem.
But I still have a doupt that this problem is related to jetty.

Comment: I just downloaded activemq-rar-5.14.5 and it does not contain these jars. That class is fouling up your JNDI lookups.

Comment: Yes it doesn't, but I need jetty to use websocket over mqtt with activemq.
I added the jar by myself from activemq.rar which contains all optional jars.

Comment: You're going to have to provide more detail as to what you're doing because that make no sense at all. WildFly 10 already uses ActiveMQ for messaging, but you have deployed your own version of it somehow?

Comment: I am not using wildfly, I am obliged to use jboss AS7 in my work.
As for what I am doing, I am deploying activemq within my jboss, and I declared a WS connector into my broker-config "transportConnector name="ws+mqtt" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:1883" in order to be able to connect a websocket client to my broker. Actually, this is why I added the netty jars, otherwise, I can't use this connector and deployment fails.

Comment: To be clear it is "JBoss AS 7" and not "JBoss EAP 7". The two are very different.

Comment: Yes it's jboss-as-7.1.1.Final.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146172/discussion-between-steve-c-and-aymen-ragoubi).

Answer (score 0):

As I posted at http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/Adding-activemq-jetty-all-jar-for-using-ws-doesn-t-allow-me-anymore-getting-jboss-exposed-ejb-tp4727190p4727305.html, I believe your question boils down to the following:

*When a webapp deployed to JBoss contains jetty-all.jar, the Jetty classes cause the default InitialContext to be created as a Jetty class. How can I get a JBoss InitialContext instead, to allow lookups of EJBs exposed by JBoss?*

It seems like the Jetty JAR is setting the InitialContextFactory class property to something Jetty-specific, overriding the JBoss-specific value set by the JBoss JARs. To force it back to the JBoss class, can you try setting the following option when creating your InitialContext?

`props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
    org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");`

If the problem really is just that you're getting the wrong JNDI context, that line should solve the problem.

Comment: Now when I try to get EJB I am getting this:
**Stopping MQTTSocket_890308146 because Failed with SecurityException: EJB client context selector may not be changed**.

I think that this is related to the fact that I am connecting to jboss server from a code running in the jetty server.

Could you help me with this ?

Comment: For reference, the OP's new post about the error referenced in his comment is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44653347/ejb-client-context-selector-may-not-be-changed.