# EJB client context selector may not be changed

Tags: ejb, jboss7.x, selector, jndi

I am trying to access an ejb that is exposed in jbossAS7.1 from code running in an embedded jetty server:

```
final Properties jndiProperties = new Properties();
jndiProperties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
jndiProperties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://127.0.0.1:4447");
jndiProperties.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
jndiProperties.put("jboss.naming.client.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT", "false");
jndiProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "ubiant");
jndiProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "ubiant2iA");
ctx = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);

Object b = ctx.lookup("ejb:Hemis/HemisCoreClient//" + "HardwareDataManagement" + "!" + "com.ubiant.hemis.client.ejb.interf.I_HardwareDataManagement");
```

But I am getting this exception:
"EJB client context selector may not be changed"

Could someone help me with this ?

Here the full stacktrace:

> 11:17:43,003 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119)
>   javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to create remoting connection
>   [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to setup EJB
>   remote context]
>
> 11:17:43,011 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119)     at
>   org.jboss.naming.remote.client.ClientUtil.namingException(ClientUtil.java:36)
>
> 11:17:43,011 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119)     at
>   org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(InitialContextFactory.java:121)
>
> 11:17:43,012 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119)     at
>   javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
>
> 11:17:43,012 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119)     at
>   javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
>
> 11:17:43,012 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119)     at
>   javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:242)
>
> 11:17:43,012 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119)     at
>   javax.naming.InitialContext.(InitialContext.java:216)
>
> 11:17:43,012 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119)     at
>   authentification.TokenAuthentificationBroker.addConnection(TokenAuthentificationBroker.java:86)
>
> 11:17:43,012 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119)     at
>   org.apache.activemq.broker.MutableBrokerFilter.addConnection(MutableBrokerFilter.java:97)
>
> 11:17:43,012 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119)     at
>   org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.processAddConnection(TransportConnection.java:733)
>
> 11:17:43,012 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119)     at
>   org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagedTransportConnection.processAddConnection(ManagedTransportConnection.java:79)
>
> 11:17:43,012 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119)     at
>   org.apache.activemq.command.ConnectionInfo.visit(ConnectionInfo.java:139)
>
> 11:17:43,012 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119)     at
>   org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.service(TransportConnection.java:292)
>
> 11:17:43,012 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119)     at
>   org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection$1.onCommand(TransportConnection.java:149)
>
> 11:17:43,012 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119)     at
>   org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.doConsume(TransportSupport.java:83)
>
> 11:17:43,012 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119)     at
>   org.apache.activemq.transport.ws.MQTTSocket.sendToActiveMQ(MQTTSocket.java:112)
>
> 11:17:43,012 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119)     at
>   org.apache.activemq.transport.mqtt.MQTTProtocolConverter.sendToActiveMQ(MQTTProtocolConverter.java:133)
>
> 11:17:43,012 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119)     at
>   org.apache.activemq.transport.mqtt.MQTTProtocolConverter.onMQTTConnect(MQTTProtocolConverter.java:235)
>
> 11:17:43,012 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119)     at
>   org.apache.activemq.transport.mqtt.MQTTProtocolConverter.onMQTTCommand(MQTTProtocolConverter.java:157)
>
> 11:17:43,012 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119)     at
>   org.apache.activemq.transport.ws.MQTTSocket.onMessage(MQTTSocket.java:59)
>
> 11:17:43,012 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketConnectionRFC6455$WSFrameHandler.onFrame(WebSocketConnectionRFC6455.java:860)
>
> 11:17:43,012 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketParserRFC6455.parseNext(WebSocketParserRFC6455.java:349)
>
> 11:17:43,012 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketConnectionRFC6455.handle(WebSocketConnectionRFC6455.java:225)
>
> 11:17:43,012 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628)
>
> 11:17:43,012 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
>
> 11:17:43,012 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
>
> 11:17:43,012 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
>
> 11:17:43,012 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119)     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> 11:17:43,012 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119) Caused by:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to setup EJB remote context
>
> 11:17:43,012 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119)     at
>   org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.setupEjbContext(InitialContextFactory.java:438)
>
> 11:17:43,012 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119)     at
>   org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(InitialContextFactory.java:115)
>
> 11:17:43,012 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119)     ... 25 more
>
> 11:17:43,012 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119) Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>
> 11:17:43,012 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>
> 11:17:43,012 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>
> 11:17:43,028 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>
> 11:17:43,028 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>
> 11:17:43,028 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119)     at
>   org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.setupEjbContext(InitialContextFactory.java:420)
>
> 11:17:43,028 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119)     ... 26 more
>
> 11:17:43,028 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119) Caused by:
>   java.lang.SecurityException: EJB client context selector may not be
>   changed
>
> 11:17:43,028 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119)     at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.setSelector(EJBClientContext.java:181)
>
> 11:17:43,028 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119)     at
>   org.jboss.naming.remote.client.ejb.RemoteNamingEjbClientContextSelector.setupSelector(RemoteNamingEjbClientContextSelector.java:18)
>
> 11:17:43,028 ERROR [stderr] (qtp10117087-119)     ... 31 more

Comment: Can you please post the stack trace? Also, which of the above lines is the one that throws the exception?

Comment: Also, are you trying to do a remote (i.e. Jetty-to-JBoss) lookup, or are you trying to do a direct lookup (relying on the fact that you're ultimately running within JBoss)? It looks to me like you're using a little bit of each approach, which is probably not what you want to do.

Comment: I edited my post and added stacktrace. I am trying to do a remote lookup from a jar placed into activemq rar which is deployed within jboss. Activemq is deployed as a rar placed into standalone/deployment repository of jboss. The jar is used to intercept client connection to the broker [http://activemq.apache.org/interceptors.html]. The ejb call is done into the jar. Actually, it's the context.lookup that throws the exception.
Also,  the list of names bound in named context is empty, and I am sure the ejbs are exposed(I can see them in the log when I launch jboss).

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developer.jboss.org/thread/273859, "Setting jboss.naming.client.ejb.context = true tries to create an EJB client context selector but it is already created for the JBoss EAP 6 instance," so "It is not possible to change the ejbSelector if the client run inside the [JBoss] server", as you're doing. The recommendation in that thread is to use the scoped-context feature ([7.5.4. Using Scoped EJB Client Contexts](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.1/html/Development_Guide/Using_Scoped_EJB_Client_Contexts.html)) for a situation like yours.

BTW, I was thinking that the other approach that might work is to go back to doing a local (non-remote) lookup that relies on the fact that your code is ultimately running inside of JBoss, as you were originally trying to do in your first question ([Get EJB object inside rar deployed inside jboss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44392545/get-ejb-object-inside-rar-deployed-inside-jboss/44611590)). But https://developer.jboss.org/thread/273428 say "You need to implement the Remote interface to be able to look it up from a different application ear/jar," so I think that's not a viable option, and the way you're approaching it (doing a remote invocation) sounds like the right approach.

**EDIT 1, based on the comment on 6/23/2017:**

Based on the "Pre-requisites of remotely accessible JNDI objects" section of https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/Remote+EJB+invocations+via+JNDI+-+EJB+client+API+or+remote-naming+project, EJBs are only remotely exposed when they satisfy two conditions:

> 1) Such objects should be bound under the java:jboss/exported/
>   namespace. For example, java:jboss/exported/foo/bar
>
> 2) Objects bound to the java:jboss/exported/ namespace are expected to be serializable.
>   This allows the objects to be sent over the wire to the remote clients

When I look at the logs showing EJBs being registered from [your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44392545/get-ejb-object-inside-rar-deployed-inside-jboss/), I don't see anything to indicate that the EJB you're trying to access is being bound under the `java:jboss/exported/` namespace. For the remote lookup to work, I think you'll also need to figure out how to bind your EJB under that namespace, in addition to using a scoped context.

Comment: Unfortunately, even with the scoped-context feature it doesn't work, and the context is always empty.

Comment: I don' understand why your saying that there is anything to indicate that the EJB you're trying to access is being bound under the java:jboss/exported/ namespace. 
Yes, the EJB is being bound under java:jboss/exported/ and this is indicated in logs in the original question.

Comment: I apologize, I missed it in the list of exported namespaces, so that doesn't appear to be the problem you're encountering. What about the question of whether your HemisClient implements Serializable (item #2 that I quoted in my EDIT 1)?

Comment: I am putting the @Remote annotation.

Comment: If you do this style of lookup (a remote lookup with scoped contexts) from a simple webapp that doesn't include the ActiveMQ and Jetty JARs, does it work?